# Show Foreign Key Data in view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem like below :
I have 3 tables MenuFront, News and SubNews. MenuFront table containt a list of link. Then in News will containt content of each kind & has foreign key with MenuFront.
 Some times in News they store as link then detail will store in SubNews then when i write a query to query out News but cannot get the SubNews information.
This is the Controller

```
public partial class Loyalty_News
{
    public Loyalty_News()
    {
        this.Loyalty_SubNews = new HashSet<Loyalty_SubNews>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LikeCount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> IsHot { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CDate { get; set; }
    public string LUser { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LDate { get; set; }
    public int MenuFrontID { get; set; }

    public virtual Loyalty_MenuFront Loyalty_MenuFront { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Loyalty_SubNews> Loyalty_SubNews { get; set; }
}
```

Then here's then query

```
if (SubMenu != "" && SubMenu != null && Menu != null && Menu != "")
        {
            var news = from a in db.Loyalty_News
                       join b in db.Loyalty_SubNews on a.Id equals b.NewsId
                       where a.Id == Int32.Parse(Menu) && b.NewsId == Int32.Parse(SubMenu)
                       select a;
            if (fromdate != null)
            {
                news = news.Where(m => m.CDate >= fromdate);
            }
            if (todate != null)
            {
                DateTime newtodate = todate ?? DateTime.Now;
                news = news.Where(m => m.LDate <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(newtodate, 1));
            }
            return View(news);
        }
        else
        {
            var news = from a in db.Loyalty_News
                       join b in db.Loyalty_SubNews on a.Id equals b.NewsId
                       select a;
            if (Menu != null && Menu != "")
            {
                news = news.Where(m => m.Id == Int32.Parse(Menu));
            }
            if (fromdate != null)
            {
                news = news.Where(m => m.CDate >= fromdate);
            }
            if (todate != null)
            {
                DateTime newtodate = todate ?? DateTime.Now;
                news = news.Where(m => m.LDate <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(newtodate, 1));
            }
            return View(news);
        }
```

And in View when i type

```
@item.Loyalty_SubNews.
```

it should show the columns of SubNews but now it only show methods (eg: Where, Union,ToList, ....)

Please help me to get the data of SubNews.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet

```
@foreach (var item in Loyalty_SubNews) //because it is list you can't get properties directly, you need to return in loop
        {
     <p> @item.property </p>   // now here the properties of Loyalty_Subnews will appear

}
```